# Some Code is not shown as covered by xdebug

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I am making unit tests and after creating a test that covers all test cases xDebug does not show some of my code as covered.

The 'slide' and default cases are shown as not covered even though I have test cases that cover both.

```
switch ($fileType) {
        case "video":
        case "pdf":
            //save content to file name
            Storage::put($path . $key . '.' . $ext, File::get($file));

            //save data to db
            $dataId = $key;
            break;
        case "slide":
            Storage::makeDirectory($path . $key);
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($file as $f) {
                Storage::put($path . $key . '/slide-' . $i++ . '.' . $ext, File::get($f));
            }

            $dataId = $key . '-' . --$i;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;

    }
```

Comment: The one in `default` is probably because you have break after `return`, which will never be hit.

Comment: And the one in `slide` is because there's no `return`, maybe?